# Entity framework raw SQL - string date format isn't correct?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, datetime-format

I have a keyless table (which isn't my handywork) and I am trying to use raw sql to insert the row of data. I did try mapping a stored procedure but I had the same problem with the date.

```
internal bool InsertSession(Guid UserID, DateTime LastActivityDate, string SessionID)
        {
            string s = "INSERT INTO aspnet_Custom_UserSessionActivity VALUES (" + "'" + UserID.ToString() + "'" + " ," + LastActivityDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "," + "'" + SessionID.ToString() + "')";

            try
            {
                using (ALFDataContext)
                {
                    ALFDataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(s);
                    ALFDataContext.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This is what string s contains:

```
INSERT INTO aspnet_Custom_UserSessionActivity VALUES ('f4da4c0b-d94e-4f9c-84ef-c82fa442bbc1' ,2014-02-04 09:48:43,'wj4gesi3bdqytflifnzyqx2c')
```

and this is the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '09'.

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at MembershipProvider.DataAccess.Repository.InsertSession(Guid UserID, DateTime LastActivityDate, String SessionID) in c:\Users\nickgowdy\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ALF source code\ALF\branches\Nick's Branch\MembershipProvider\DataAccess\Repository.cs:line 149
```

I am assuming my date format is wrong but I can't see the bug.

Does anyone have suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: Well, you've just managed to prove that ORMs don't automatically protect from [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html)!

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT**, under *any* circumstances, use string concatenation to insert parameters into a query!

By building a dynamic SQL query, you've just opened yourself up to [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html).

Avoiding SQL Injection with Entity Framework is *extremely* simple:

```
internal bool InsertSession(Guid UserID, DateTime LastActivityDate, string SessionID)
{
   try
   {
      using (ALFDataContext)
      {
         string s = "INSERT INTO aspnet_Custom_UserSessionActivity VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2})";
         ALFDataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(s, UserID, LastActivityDate, SessionID);
         // No need to call SaveChanges here.
         return true;
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

The `ExecuteSqlCommand` method will automatically create a parameterized query, and replace the `{0}`, `{1}` and `{2}` tokens in the string with the correct parameter names.